# SVN Merge Conflict Oddities

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm using TortoiseSVN. I reverted all local change to my branch. I verified that I had no local changes.  I then merged another branch into the current branch WC. For UnitofWork.cs, which is now conflicted, I end up with these files:

- UnitOfWork.cs
- UnitOfWork.cs.merge-left.r2187
- UnitOfWork.cs.merge-right.r2449
- UnitOfWork.cs.working

Given that I had no local changes, I would expect that UnitOfWork.cs.working would match either the revision 2187 or 2449 file, but it varies a lot from both of them of them.

When I compare the r2187 and r2449 files they are very similar, just 3 line differences.

When I edit this file's conflicts TortoiseSVN's merge tool shows 5 conflicts on non-contiguous lines.

Shouldn't UnitOfWork.cs.working match either the 2187 or 2449 revision file? Under what circumstance does it not match either (and yes I'm certain I've no working copy changes)?

If only 3 lines vary, is it odd that TortoiseSVN's merge tool shows 5 separate conflicts on non-concurrent lines?

Comment: Why do you remove the [tag:svn] tag from this question?

Comment: @bahrep Have you an answer to the question asked?

Comment: maybe, but I haven’t tried to understand the problem you describe. Tagging the question correctly can attract more readers and increases the chance for the question to receive an answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, those conflict files are generic to Subversion, not anything specific to TortoiseSVN.